Vue: returning non-reactive values from a composable
Is it okay to return non-reactive values from a composable?
E.g., like so:
// useNavLink.js

import { toValue } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default function useNavLink(link) {
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleLinkClick = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault()

    router.push(toValue(link))
  }

  return { handleLinkClick }
}

// NavLink.vue

<template>
  <a :href="link" @click="handleLinkClick">{{ label }}</a>
</template>

<script setup>
import useNavLink from '@/composables/useNavLink'

const { link, label } = defineProps(['link', 'label'])

const { handleLinkClick } = useNavLink(() => link)
</script>

The docs say the following,

The recommended convention is for composables to always return a plain, non-reactive object containing multiple refs.

but they don't explicitly say that one shouldn't return non-reactive values.

totally ok, you don't need everything reactive really in real life

The mentioned section suggests this vs returning single reactive() object. It's true that "they don't explicitly say that one shouldn't return non-reactive values". No reason why this wouldn't be ok
